# HowTo Install a Package in Julia 1.0

Tags: julia

Being a 1.0 release I thought Julia would be easier to get started with. I enter package manager and, yeah, do the whole add Package thing. You can see the failure below. What's going on here? 
I checked the potential insteadOf fix, it doesn't help me. Kind of lost as how to proceed. I regularly use git with other frameworks on my machine, thus struggle to believe this is a git configuration issue. I'm posting this on stackOverflow, so I guess I am connected to the internet :)

```
(v1.0) pkg> add DataFrames
   Cloning default registries into C:\Users\uabc\.julia\registries
   Cloning registry General from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git
"
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git, erro
r: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:Net, malformed URL 'http://10.23.28.130:8080;PROXY
')

(v1.0) pkg>
```

Comment: As a short-term fix, if git works fine, you could clone the package and then us `pkg> add path/to/repo`. You might also include more details about your proxy setup and your git configuration. Lots of people are using julia's package manager just fine behind proxies, so I struggle to believe it's an issue with the package manager alone. See also https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/24835

Comment: You may also get better help asking at http://discourse.julialang.org/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For 1.0
use the following command

> using Pkg
>
> Pkg.add("Flux")

Answer (score 10):

Where there is a problem with package installation you can always try (after going to package manager with `]`) to install a development version of the package.

```
add DataFrames#master
```

or

```
develop DataFrames
```

or

```
add https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl
```

However, I would assume that you have some git proxy setting related problem. Please check if other packages are installing correctly.